# Php Custom Mvc - how to check if function gets arguments?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, class, function

Im working lately on a custom mvc for php, and one of the question was really bothered me:
Ive got the controller class, and i want to check if a certain function of the class getting arguments, and if not, return false.

is there any method to do it?
cause i searched in php.net and google and didn't find anything....
thanx!

Comment: Can you please clarify: do you want to check from the outside if a certain method takes arguments? Or do you want to check from inside a method if it's receiving arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php):

```
$reflection = new ReflectionMethod ($class_name, $method_name);
$params = $r->getParameters();
```

`$params` is now an array of [ReflectionParameter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionparameter.php) objects

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`func_get_args`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

You can use it inside the method in your controller to get the list of all arguments passed to the method.

You also have [`func_num_args`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) that will just give you the number of arguments passed to your method.

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems to me the OP wishes to see, from outside the function, if a function/method accepts arguments.

Comment: I thought so too at first, but then he says he wants the method to return false. He will let us know in time :)

Comment: OK. In that case Reflection is pretty much your only choice. Beware of using it too much, as it will make your code 1000x more difficult to debug, especially when someone external starts to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Use function func_get_args

```
function sum(){
    $s=0;
    foreach(func_get_args() as $a) $s+= is_numeric($a)?$a:0;
    return $s;
};

print sum(1,2,3,4,5,6); // 21
```